# Зацикливание

Tags: java, beanshell

Не могу разобраться, что не так с данным циклом.

```
byte[] b = writeLen(command);
long retLen = b.length + command.length() + 1;
byte[] ret = new byte[retLen];
print(b.length);        
for (i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
  print(i);
  ret[i] = b[i];
}
print("^");
```

При выполнении скрипт не может выйти из цикла for. Вывод команды получается таким:

6
*
1
0
0
0
0
0
и до бесконечности нули.

Шестерка и звездочка выводятся из процедуры WriteLen перед выходом из нее. Единица - длина b. А в цикле происходит чудо - счетчик остается неизменным.

Comment: Был long, поменял на int, но ничего не изменилось.

Answer (score 1):

используйте System.arraycopy() для копирования массива.

Comment: С system.arraycopy этот участок работает. Но по настоящему проблема решилась когда я объявил int i не внутри блока try, а в общем блоке процедуры.

Answer (score 1):

Сдается что в реальности там так
for (i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
  print(i);
  i = b[i];
}

Answer (score 0):

Судя по коду у вас не задан тип переменной i, лучше написать другой заголовок:

```
for(int i=0; i<b.length; i++)
```

Comment: По идее это не мешает выполнению. Вот, например, я запускаю <br/>

for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) { print(i); }

И это прекрасно работает как bsh, так и в bsh2

Comment: По идее не мешает. Но вы же видите что код вполне разумный, поэтому я думаю это один из вариантов.